# Format java.sql.Timestamp into a String

Tags: java

Is it possible to convert/format `java.sql.Timestmap` into a String that has the following format:

> yyyyMMdd

I know that doing it with a `String` is fairly simple e.g:

```
String dateString = "2016-02-03 00:00:00.0";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S").parse(dateString);
String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(date);
```

But, I have to work with the `Timestamp` object.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could do something like so:

```
Timestamp ts = ...;
Date date = new Date();
date.setTime(ts.getTime());
String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(date);
```

Comment: Timestamp extends Date

Comment: @Kashyap: I do not quite get your comment.

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat.format()` will accept type `Timestamp`. No need to create a `new Date()`.

Comment: This approach is bad code, inefficient. Please see better answer by @Robert Bräutigam.

Comment: there are different `Date` classes, can you specify which `Date` class you mean?

Comment: @Sim: This is a very old post, however I was most likely referring to the `java.util.Date` class.

Answer (score 39):

The `java.sql.Timestamp` extends `java.util.Date`, so you can format it exactly the same way:

```java
String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(date);
```

Parsing is almost the same, you can construct it using its "millis" representation:

```java
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse(formattedDate).getTime());
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the (not so) new `java.time` package:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");

String convert(Timestamp ts) {
    return ts.toLocalDateTime().format(FORMATTER);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [www.joda.org/joda-time/](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

```
public static String timestampAsString(Timestamp timestamp) {
    return DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd").print(timestamp.getTime());
}
```